# Receiving the following error: TypeError: float argument required, not instance

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am implementing a big circle class,which does operations like computes area,compares two circle,compares a circle and square etc,but i am having trouble with this small snippet.

```
class Circle(Point):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, r=0):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y
        self.R = r
        self.area = math.pi*r*r

    def __str__(self):
        return ("A Circle which has centre at " + "(" + "%0.6f" % (self.X) + ", "
                + "%0.6f" % (self.Y) + ")" + "and its radius " + "%0.6f" % (self.R))

    def getX(self):
        return self.X

    def getY(self):
        return self.Y

    def getR(self):
        return self.R

    def setR(self):
        pass

    def area(self):
        return math.pi * self.R * self.R


def main():
    x = float(input("Enter x coordinate of first circle's centre: "))
    y = float(input("Enter y coordinate of the first circle's centre: "))
    r = float(input("Enter first circle's radius: "))
    pointx1 = x
    pointy1 = y
    radius1 = r
    first_circle = Circle(x, y, r)
    print(first_circle)
    print("\nArea of  first circle is %0.6f" % (first_circle, first_circle.area())
main()
```

However i get the following error on executing the below code:

```
print("\nArea of  first circle is %0.6f" % (first_circle, first_circle.area))
TypeError: float argument required, not instance
```

How do i get rid of this.I have calculated self.area in constructor as because i am using it later(haven't shown the code here) to compare two circle's areas which are being sent as argument.Please help.

Comment: Why are there 2 arguments in your string formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first argument in your string format:

```
print("\nArea of  first circle is %0.6f" % (first_circle.area()))
```

I'm not sure why you put `first_circle` as an argument since `%0.6f` is the only part of the string requiring an argument.

---

Also you need to either rename `self.area` or rename the method `area()` because it causes conflicts if they have the same name.